# Why cell takes over Format from linked cell and how to prevent this?

Tags: excel, format

One Cell collects Data from several others e.g. like this `=(ROUNDUP(IFERROR((SUM(C9:C22)-N183)/M14,0) ... +M618+M646,0))+0` this cell has the format "Standard". One or more cells where the numbers are collected from is user defined format, in this case e.g. `0" m"` or `"pro "0`or`"dia "Standart`.

Why Excel changes the Format when the Value in cell changes? This happens even when simply activating the cell by doubleclick or F2. The cell takes the Format from the cell of values origin, but only for cells with user defined format.

How to prevent this.

There is no VBA behind this cells.

Comment: *How to prevent this?* I'm afraid that's the default behaviour of Excel and it's pretty annoying sometimes. There is no way you can avoid it. Every time you double click on that cell or edit it, it will do the same. There's a trick [using Text format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/format-numbers-f27f865b-2dc5-4970-b289-5286be8b994a) but this makes the final value to be treated as text so if this cell is used in other formulas cannot be read as numeric by default. Another option would be "do not edit that cell". Do you really need to double click on it very often?

Comment: hi thx for your reply, the cells have to edit often (e.g. add something to the formula etc.)... I could imagine to set the format with VBA each time it changes but I wanted to avoid such things...

Comment: Try something: because you want to keep standard format in that cell, I guess you just want a numeric value. Trap your original formula inside '=VALUE(your original formula)'. This should return just a numeric value and should avoid the autoformatting...

Comment: ... and if its treated as text it schould show the formula as text instead the value, doesn't it?
thats amazing THX! `=VALUE(your original formula)`

Comment: Nope, VALUE combined with a text value will raise an error. You probably could handle the error with an IFERROR

Comment: post it as an answer i will vote for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to keep standard format in that cell, trap your original formula inside `=VALUE(your original formula)`.

This should return just a numeric value and should avoid the autoformatting. If your formula returns a text value at any moment, `VALUE` will raise an error but you could handle it adding `IFERROR` as you need.

Comment: This behaviour drives me nuts! for some cells it works great, for some not... e.g. cell with 
`=VALUE(ROUNDUP(IFERROR(SUM(C9:C22)/M14,0)+IFERROR(SUM(C186:C199)/M191,0)+IFERROR(SUM(C369:C380)/M374,0)+SUM(S175:S182)+SUM(S358:S365)+SUM(S504:S511)+M618+M646,0))+0` 
works perfect while a part of cells with origin values are `0" m"` formatted. For cells with formula
`=VALUE(ROUNDUP(M622,0))+0`
it won't work at all while cells with origin value (M622) are `0,00" m"` formatted.
Any Idea?

Comment: found the following out: `=VALUE(M622)` will not work but `=VALUE(M622*1)` works perfekt (divide by 1 is also possible). Who knows whats the sense behind it, is it sense?

Comment: @BugFix It could be `M622` is returning a numeric value but is returned as text and doing `*1` forces it to be read as numeric

Comment: Nope, it seems a different thing. For example, I have a formula that only adds the results from tables, the same thing happens there.  Multiplied by 1 makes it fine... and as i wrote custom format setting is `0" m"` and this is numeric